# Editing shape/illustration/textbox/whatever-it-is in Word

Tags: ms-word

Can somebody please explain me why I can't edit the text in this file [LINK](https://ufile.io/phg6w).
(file name is ask.docx)? And I would also like to know how I need to change it, please.

I am using Word 2016, and clicking on this shape/illustration/textbox or whatever-it-is has been driving me crazy.

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think this question was even remotely on topic?

Answer (score 0):

The document in your link has no text - just some graphical objects, some of which have been created from text. To edit the 'text' you'd need to extract the objects and open them in an appropriate graphics application.